# Why isn't this Python replace function working?

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm trying to remove a set of characters from a larger string. Here's what I've tried:

```
string = 'aabc'
remove = 'ac'
for i in remove:
    string.replace(i, '', 1)
print(string)
```

I keep getting back my original string when I run this. The variable `i` is getting the characters 'a' and then 'c'. The replace function works for me if i do `string.replace('a', '', 1)`. Why isn't this working or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: help(str.replace) --> _Return a copy of string S with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
given, only the first count occurrences are replaced._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable in python, so `string.replace()` does not mutate the string; it returns a new string with the replacements.

Try this:

```
string = string.replace(i, '', 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

`replace` returns a new string.

Strings in python are immutable.

As such, you must assign the return value:

```
string_new = "ABCD".replace("A","Z")
```

Answer (score 1):

A new string will be generated as Strings are immutable...

Try this -

```
string = 'aabc'
remove = 'ac'
for i in remove:
    result = string.replace(i, '', 1)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Strings are immutable you cant use `replace` with just `string.replace()`.
As a better way use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) :

```
>>> s='aabcc'
>>> s=''.join(set(s))
'acb'
```